# When temperature is only caused by translational kinetic energy, why does microwaves heat water by rotation?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, microwaves

I thought microwaves causing water molecules to rotate, thus raising the temperature of my food but temperature isn't caused by rotation or vibration degree of freedom:

> We also pointed out that temperature is a measure of the average kinetic energy **due to translational motions of molecules**. If vibrational or rotational motions are also active, these will also accept thermal energy and reduce the amount that goes into translational motions. **Because the temperature depends only on the latter**, the effect of the other kinds of motions will be to reduce the dependence of the internal energy on the temperature, thus raising the heat capacity of a substance.

https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Chem1_(Lower)/14%3A_Thermochemistry/14.03%3A_Molecules_as_Energy_Carriers_and_Converters

Comment: Did you look up the corresponding Wiki articles, in particular the one on [dielectric heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_heating) linked in the [principles section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven#Principles) of the microwave oven article?

Comment: It doesn't really matter how you dump thermal energy into a complex interconnected system. All the internal interactions in the system will distribute the energy into all the ways the system can have energy until steady state is reached.

Comment: @gs so what you are saying is: Temperature indeed just depends on translational and if I dump energy that initially is stored in form of rotation into my system, that will fastly spread into translation (in a solid it's vibration, not the same vibration as the common vibrational mode but vibration of the whole molecule around a steady center)?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's an accurate definition of temperature except for an ideal gas, hence giving a comment and not an answer, but yes to the other part.

Comment: @gs I always wondered, why would (hypothetical) pure rotation or vibration doesn't cause any temperature? I mean those are movements too, just not as "large" as translation...

Comment: Randomly distributed Pure rotation doesn't stay pure rotation in an interconnected system. Consider a room full of car tyres piled halfway to the ceiling. One of them is attached to a wheel and axle and powerful motor bolted to the wall so that it sits a little above the floor. We start the engine, adding energy to the systemvia the rotation of the attached wheel. How does the room look a few seconds later?

Comment: @gs yes, I already got that. That's because I wrote "hypothetical", so exclude the possibility of translation for a moment, why wouldn't energy in form of rotation and/ or vibration cause any temperature (why why wouldn't it cause a warm feeling when touched), even if things move a little (molecules spinning or parts of the molecule wiggle due to vibration).

Comment: Why, for temperature, the molecule as a whole have to move like in translation?